# OSX: Changing parent view from subview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Right now when my application loads, it loads a login view

```
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
    [mainView addSubview:[loginViewController view]];
```

So after a user clicks login, I need to change the `mainView`. What would be the best way to go about this? How can I access the `mainView` from my `LoginViewController`?

Edit: 
I've changed my button action to release itself from the parent view, but it doesn't seem to load the next view I want to load.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Pressed login button");

[[self view] removeFromSuperview];

TimerViewController *timerViewController = [[TimerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimerView" bundle:nil];
[[[self view] superview] addSubview:[timerViewController view]];
}
```

Comment: Where did mainView come from? Why doesn't it have a corresponding view controller?

Comment: mainView is in AppDelegate. Its the just the default view made when creating a new project in xcode. Should it have its own controller? If so, how can I make these views interact with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do it in the opposite order, add the TimerViewController to the superview before removing your login view from the superview, or create a LoginViewDelegate protocol that the main view subscribes too.